# SharePoint 2016 patch advice

Tags: sharepoint, patch

I have got a question here as I recently extended my role (from Senior SharePoint developer) also as a SharePoint administrator and applying SharePoint product patches on the servers now is a part of my job. The responsibility is new and am also learning at the same time.

The last patch applied by the previous admin was in May 2018. I can see that there are a lot of patches released by Microsoft every month and since we are lagging way behind what should be my approach in getting the patches applied?

Reading a couple of articles suggests that I should be very mindful before making a call to proceed with the patch activity in the sense look out for any issues that might arise out of the patch etc.. at the sametime since the environment is lagging behind with updates I need to advice the management on an approach to stay inline with updates.

Any suggestion/recommendation is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly deploy the latest patch package in SharePoint 2016.

After each successful installation, you need to run SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard.

[image]

- [Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016: July 13, 2021 (KB5001976)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2016-july-13-2021-kb5001976-b076ed39-12e6-4e4e-bc08-1667064c5f0c)
- [Description of the security update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016(MUI/language patch): July 13, 2021 (KB5001981)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2016-july-13-2021-kb5001981-3e665233-943e-4cf5-946b-8ee5517acb4a)

Comment: Thank you, we have a Web server and an app server so I am assuming the update has to be installed separately in both environments? Thanks

Comment: Ensure that the same version of the patch package is installed in both environments